# Detail View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I just downloaded the new xcode. I had done some iOS a few months ago, but am now trying to pick it up again. What is Detail View Controller and how does it relate to Master View Controller? I don't recall seeing this before so I didn't know if it was a part of the new xcode. In xcode 5 I thought you just created different view controllers and linked them all together.

Comment: Read the documentation before asking questions: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/SplitViewControllers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are just the names Xcode gives to the default view controllers when you create a new project.  You can change them at your pleasure.

Comment: Ok so presumably I can just delete them and re-make them similar to how the original xcode (xcode 5) was set up?

Comment: At a Glance -
Familiarize yourself with the view controllers that you can use in your app. Although you can build an app
entirely from custom view controllers, using the provided view controllers reduces the amount of code you
have to write and helps you maintain a consistent user experience.

Comment: Yes, you can delete them and build your own.  I noticed the same when I started a new project.  Presumably if you start with a different template you won't get them.  When you delete them, I'd do a project search to see if the names are used somewhere else before adding the new ones, just in case Xcode dropped them in somewhere.